# SQL with OR operator bad performance

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlperformance

I have a table with an indexed field `year`, and I'm experiencing bad performance with some query and I can' understand why. With a query like this:

```
select ..... where year = 2016 ...
```

I'm getting good performance, but with a query like this:

```
select .... where ((year = 2016 and month = 1) or (year = 2015 and month = 7)) ...
```

things turn really slow...why is not used the index over the `year` field in this last case? I know why the perfomance would be bad in a query like:

```
select .... where year = 2016 or month = 1
```

But why in my case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Gordon's answer is clearly the best choice. Otherwise, if for whatever reason you wouldn't be able to create the index on (year, month), another option would be to rewrite the query as a UNION ALL. Each branch of the UNION ALL will run fast, and then so will the total query. Since the two conditions separated by OR are mutually exclusive, you will get the exact same duplicates with UNION ALL (if any) as you would with the OR condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an index on `year` and `month` and use:

```
where (year, month) in ( (2016, 1), (2015, 7) )
```

Oracle should be smart enough to use the composite index for your query.  This version is more concise and easier to write and to read.